# Autowidth is not working for merged columns

Tags: apache-poi

```
{
row=sheet.createRow(0);
cell=row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("header");
cell=row.createCell(1);
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,1));
row=sheet.createRow(1);
cell=row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Keys");
cell=row.createCell(1);
cell=row.setCellValue("Values");
row=sheet.createRow(2);
cell=row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("No data");
cell=row.createCell(1);
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,0,1);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
}
```

autosize is working when I merged two columns of row zero, but after merging two columns of second row autosize is not working..
thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you define "not working"? Sizes too small? Too big? No change?

Comment: no change in columns

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've spotted your problem, it's this line:

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
```

From the [javadocs on autoSizeColumn(int)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29) we see this key bit of information:

> Default is to ignore merged cells.

You need to switch to instead call [autoSizeColumn(int,boolean)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int,%20boolean%29), and pass in a true value. This will tell POI to take account of merged cells during the sizing. So, your code should instead be:

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0, true);
```