# excel cells get shrinked on different machine even when code is same using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have developed a `java` code for downloading excel sheet. I am using `apache POI`. This thing `worked well on all machine`.

However when `same code` deployed to `different server` the `cells got Shrinked` to very small width `even though the cells were having the data`.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using auto-sized columns and fonts are not setup correctly.

See [Apache POI autoSizeColumn Resizes Incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943493/apache-poi-autosizecolumn-resizes-incorrectly) for related question

Comment: I am using 'Arial' font which is very basic. This may not need installing font in Java.